# Who is the inventor of slovin's formula?

Tags: statistics, math-history

And how can I use it in the population contain 10000 people with confidence interval 95%?

Also, why there is only a few information about the inventor in the web?

Comment: At first I thought of "Who's buried in Grant's Tomb." But Wikipedia editors seem to be grasping to discover person and date of origin, general principle vs. proof, usefulness, etc. It is apparently a formula utterly without distributional conditions on the sample size needed to achieve specified confidence bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](http://www.philstat.org.ph/files/images/2012_611_9_On_the_Misuse_of_Slovin_s_Formula.pdf) for a review of Slovin's formula, where they say there is no person called Slovin they can atribute the formula to.